# RuntimeError: CUDA unknown error - this may be due to an incorrectly set up environment, e.g. changing env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES

Tags: ubuntu, python3, cuda

I am trying to check the GPU device name but after executing this code. I got this unknown runtime error. please help me to solve this problem and give complete instructions to solve this error. Thanks.

```
(base) kumar@kumar:~$ conda activate pytorch
        (pytorch) kumar@kumar:~$ python
        Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) 
        [GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
        Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
        >>> import torch
        >>> print(torch.__version__)
        1.9.0a0+gitb39eeb0
        >>> print(torch.version.cuda)
        11.2
        >>> print(torch.cuda.current_device())
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/home/kumar/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 430, in current_device
            _lazy_init()
          File "/home/kumar/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 170, in _lazy_init
            torch._C._cuda_init()
        RuntimeError: CUDA unknown error - this may be due to an incorrectly set up environment, e.g. changing env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES after program start. Setting the available devices to be zero.
        >>> exit()
```

Here is the output of `nvcc -V`

(pytorch) kumar@kumar:~$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Feb_14_21:12:58_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.152
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29618528_0
(pytorch) kumar@kumar:~$

here is the output of `nvidia-smi`

```
Thu Apr  8 15:04:49 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.67       Driver Version: 460.39       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr: Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 3070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   38C    P8    10W / 220W |    525MiB /  7982MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1015      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 70MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1542      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                257MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1675      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               89MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3560      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       94MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, when I try to run this code:

```
print(torch.cuda.current_device())
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
              File "/home/kumar/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 430, in current_device
                _lazy_init()
              File "/home/kumar/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 170, in _lazy_init
                torch._C._cuda_init()
            RuntimeError: CUDA unknown error - this may be due to an incorrectly set up environment, e.g. changing env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES after program start. Setting the available devices to be zero.
```

Comment: Wild guess are the versions from cuda and cudnn you are using compatible?

Install:

    or CUDA 10.2 and cuDNN v8.0.2 (July 24th, 2020), for CUDA 10.2
    or CUDA 11.1 and cuDNN 8.0.5(for CUDA 11.1) - preferably